# Create multi-language in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, multilingual

I have to do a multi-language site in Joomla 2.5 or later?

for this I active the module language selector and a plugin filter language and now the router of my page is http...../es but the browser show this error.

```
The requested URL /.../es/ was not found on this server.
```

I also create content a menu, but show me the same error.
any idea.

Comment: We can barely do anything with this little information.

Comment: thanks @Marijike, finally the problem is that a project that I have to modified is allocate in windows server, so don´t need .htaccess file. So when I downloaded the project didn´t have this file. Now I create a .htaccess file but I have 3 element of menu and no routing to any item of menu, for example when I access to item presentation I obtain  presentacion.html was not found on this server. I select the friendly route in my project, if I no-activate this option everything is ok and work prefect I restart apache too, but don´t work. any idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look, I don't want to be rude, but Joomla 1.7 is really outdated and there little sense in using it noways. Consider 2.5.x or 3.x.

To answer your question, there is a really good tutorial on how to do this. Did it a lot of times and works very good.

[Language Switcher Tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/Language_Switcher_Tutorial)